# Add didSet observer on a weak property in an extension

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I am trying to make a UITextField extension which performs additional functions upon the setting of a delegate.

```
extension UITextField {
    override weak public var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
        didSet {
            print("Do stuff")

        }  
    }
}
```

This fails with three errors:

```
'delegate' used within its own type

'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '<<error type>>'

Property does not override any property from its superclass
```

What do I need to change for `Do stuff` to be printed upon the setting of the delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override delegate property using extension, you need to create subclass:

```
class TextField: UITextField {
    override weak var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
        didSet {
            super.delegate = delegate
            print("Do stuff")
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems kinda wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ultimately I was trying to see how one might call multiple delegates sequentially (instead of being limited to one). However the Observer pattern is stronger for that case anyway.